# Representation of progress, stated and delayed days of an activity

Tags: progress-bar

I'm trying to express the progress, the state and delayed days of an activity with this representation.

[image]

My representation is a progress bar with a number next to it and below there is an icon that shows the state. The progress bar visually shows the progress of the activity and the number show how many days is delayed from the end date. The state can be "completed" or "reviewing".

I would like to highlight when an activity is delayed from the end date. I mean if this number is greater than zero it would change to some color, like red. What could you suggest for doing this? paint the progress bar in red? the number? the number inside a red circle with white text?

I would also like to highlight when an activity is closed to the end with a color like yellow but also don't want too much color because the users could lose focus on the important.

Comment: There can be activities in progress with and without delay?

Comment: When stauts is completed I choose not to show delay. And delay can be a real number. Negative, Zero or Positive number.

Comment: So no, there can not be activities in progress without a delay

Comment: Just remember that you [can't (well, shouldn't) rely on color alone](https://www.w3.org/WAI/gettingstarted/tips/designing.html#dont-use-color-alone-to-convey-information) to signify "bad" versus "good" states, assuming accessibility is a concern in the context of where your application will be used.

Answer (score -1):

yes. the progress bar could be red, you could also have an intermediate color (or colors) like yellow to indicate when it's getting close to going behind schedule.

Slightly off topic, but in some management schools of thought being too far ahead of schedule is a bad thing as well, while optimally being closest to the estimate is valued the most. so you could come up with a slightly different color scheme for this.

The number could be a negative to indicate how many days behind schedule it is.

when an activity is closed and completed you could have a check mark while if its closed regardless of being completed, you could slightly lighten it.

Comment: only the bar? should the number get color too?